# What is the Data Source syntax SQL Client Connection String to Azure?

Tags: asp.net, database-connection, sqlclient

I am attempting to configure the connection string in web.confg for an ASP.NET app to connect to Azure DB.  I am new to this but am familiar with sql configuration strings to SQL Server.  How do I configure the login and data source in the connection string I am building.  I haven't ever dealt with the cloud like this.  If my db name is DB1 how do I set the Azure path for the data source portion of the connection string.  NOTE:  I know where to configure it in web.config and know to create a connection object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Azure portal, you can navigate to your database's dashboard and click 'Show connection strings' on the right side. See the first screenshot on the below tutorial:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-dotnet-how-to-use/

To answer your original question, "Data Source" means the same as "Server", it is just your server name, i.e. blah.database.windows.net. All of the connection string keywords (including their synonyms) are documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Where were you in July? ;)

Comment: Haha, sorry I missed your question for so long :)